# flutter package audio_service: Is there a way to remove the notification from the ui without stopping the service?

Tags: flutter, audio, service, notifications

Without stopping the service, my app sometimes needs to remove the  notification  when the music stops playing
(of course, the notification needs to be displayed again when some other music  playing).
Is there a soluation? Because the service switch consumes too much